# jQuery UI autocomplete in codeIgniter with sql, php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, codeigniter

[image]

I am trying to do  create text-box auto-complete with jquery. But something goes wrong when I check it in debuger it shows the every value but it not showing in text-box drop-down on view page. I'm newbie all help would be appreciated.

**here's my view code.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#location").autocomplete({
            source: 'set_location'
        });     
    });
</script>
<form action= "#">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='location'>Location</label></td>
            <td><input id="location" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" name= "location"> </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
</form>
```

**here's my controller code**

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])){
    $location = strtolower($_GET['term']);      
    $query = $this->venues_model->set_location($location);          
    echo $query;
}
```

**here's my model code**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('location', $location);
$query = $this->db->get('venue_details');

if(count($query->result_array()) > 0){ 
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['location']));
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set);
}
```

Comment: Any error in console??

Comment: No it not showing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])){
$location = strtolower($_GET['term']);      
echo $this->venues_model->set_location($location);          
}
```

in model

```
function set_location() {
    $row_set = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('location', $location);
    $query = $this->db->get('venue_details');

    if (count($query->result_array()) > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['location']));
        }

    }

    return json_encode($row_set);
}
```

also this,

```
source: '<?= base_url("controller/set_location") ?>'
```

Comment: Check i have changed my model

Comment: in console is it printing anything??

Comment: yes after every key press it update and showing the values.

Comment: can u add that screenshot??

Comment: @RahulBhargava, remove all other echo you have there like `before` `inside...`

Comment: the only echo should be that values returning from model. Thats it. It will solve your problem.

Comment: y is that text box coming in console??

Comment: i created a else block like this    else{
 $this->load->view('set_location');
 if(isset($_GET['term'])){
  $location = strtolower($_GET['term']);
  echo $this->venues_model->set_location($location);      
 }
    }

Comment: remove that load view part

Comment: in this, only echo of json should be present. no var_dump, no any other echo and no loading view

Comment: thanks @Niranjan N Raju it worked. I just give exit after json_encode. Again thank you

Comment: Glad it helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Comment: Hope you got to know why it was working in my system, not in yours, Culprits are echo and loading the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` from your model file and `echo` from your controller

**Model**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('location', $location);
$query = $this->db->get('venue_details');

if(count($query->result_array()) > 0){ 
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['location']));
    }
    return json_encode($row_set);// return from model
}
```

**Controller**

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])){
    $location = strtolower($_GET['term']);      
   echo  $query = $this->venues_model->set_location($location);          
}
```

And change your path to

```
source: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller/function'
```

Comment: You need to call a ajax [link](http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-country-example/) to get your data from your controller

Comment: i'm following this [link](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/)

Comment: YOu need to check your path i tinl it would be            source: '<?php echo base_url()./index.php/controller/function'

Comment: what is index.php here

Comment: Check without index.php `<?php echo base_url();?>controller/function`

Comment: Have you check browser console??

Comment: yes i checked there is no error and it also showing value which value we have to show in drop down..

Comment: only drop down is not coming. Value is coming in browser

Answer (score 0):

just add `ui-widget` to your div. Make sure to reference jquery ui